Is there a way to get square meters from a Teradata ST_Area call?
I can't seem to find a spatial reference system in Teradata that returns square meters from a call to ST_Area(). I've tried 1619, which seems to be the Teradata mapping to 4326, it returns square degrees (I think that's what you call it), but essentially just like I hadn't set an SRID. There is no way to set units in a call to ST_Area so this might just be a limitation. I know there's not an easy way to do the calculation but this kinda makes the ST_Area call very limited. Is it possible to get this working? Is there a call that will do this or a spatial system that can represent it so I can get square meters?
Update:
This code is what I'm seeing:
SELECT  
  "GeometryData" as Coords,
  "GeometryData".ST_Area() as Area,
  "GeometryData".ST_SRID() as Srid
FROM "geography_tests"."spatial_reference"

And the results are:



Coords
Area
Srid




POLYGON ((-100 40,-100 44,-96 44,-96 40,-100 40))
16.0
1619



Update 2
I've gone through every single coordinate system supported by Teradata and not a single one seems to return square meters, they all return decimal degrees. It sounds like this is just not supported.

I'm trying to represent 4326 (WGS84), although teradata has this as 1619. So the data is stored in this reference system, which I would expected would return ST_Area in square meters?

Do you have an example of a reference system that would allow me to get this? The coordinates could be anywhere throughout the world, lat/long? Thank you.

I've gone through every single SRID in the spatial_ref_sys table and not a single one returns anything other than decimal degrees.
